# Implement interface when extending Application class

Tags: android, interface, google-play-services

I need to use `mGoogleApiClient` across several activities so I decided to create a class `MyApplication` which `extends` the `Application` class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    public Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(mContext)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(mContext)
                .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
    }
}
```

However there is a problem with these two lines:

```
.addConnectionCallbacks(mContext)
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(mContext)
```

since I need to implement

`GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` and `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener`

and then override these methods:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
```

Is the `Application` class allowed to `implement` an `interface` in general and should I do so, or should I delete those two lines from the `mGoogleApiClient` and possibly initialize them in other activities?

I don't know how the `Application` class will handle these methods and the connection state and whether I need to implement these methods again in my other activities.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Your `MyApplication` is a subclass of `Application` specific only to your app. Android is only going to use the `Application` portion of it, but you're allowed to implement whatever you need.

But you should be aware of the fact that there can only be one instance of the application class at a time.

If you need multiple callbacks, in a case where they store state for example, having `MyApplication` implement them would not work that well due to the state changes. Instantiating an inner class would be a better option in that case.

Here it looks like you're only going to use the callbacks once, so having `MyApplication` implement them would work just fine.

The application class is a good place for instantiating things like API clients. This ensures that no more than one is created and that one is always available.

Note also that `Application` is a context, so you can use `this` instead of `mContext`.